# In R, how can I vectorize a column assignment that filters for another condition?

Tags: r

I have a data table I am assigning a new column to and I am trying to vectorize the following loop so that my code runs more efficiently. I have looked into ifelse but I don't think it works on data tables- please correct me if I'm wrong! I've seen answers for Matlab and C++ but would appreciate help on how to do it in R. Below is my assignment loop:

```
for (i in 1:20610) {
  if (table$Delta[i] > 0) {
    table$CashFlow[i] = -1*table$Buy[i]*table$Delta[i]
  }
  else {
    table$CashFlow[i] = -1*table$Sell[i]*table$Delta[i]
  }
}
```

Thank you!

[Example of data and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nmvj.png)

Comment: can you share example data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
table$CashFlow <- with(table, ifelse(Delta > 0,  -1*Buy*Delta, -1*Sell*Delta))
```

---

Or another option is to use `row/column` indexing

```
table[-1][with(table, cbind(1:nrow(table), (Delta <= 0)+1))]*-1 * table$Delta
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
table <- data.frame(Delta = rnorm(5), Buy = sample(1:10, 5,
        replace = TRUE), Sell = sample(1:7, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: You can factor out the -Delta.